# JHipster Entities Menu is Empty after succeed import-jdl

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, vuejs2, jhipster

I have just installed JHipster (VueJS) thru docker image, and I imported jdl file directly form https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/.

```
jhipster@66b8176ee05f:~/app$ jhipster import-jdl ../jhipster.jdl
INFO! Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
INFO! Executing import-jdl ../jhipster.jdl
INFO! Found .yo-rc.json on path. This is an existing app
INFO! The JDL is being parsed.
warn: In the One-to-Many relationship from Employee to Job, only bidirectionality is supported for a One-to-Many association. The other side will be automatically added.
warn: In the One-to-Many relationship from Department to Employee, only bidirectionality is supported for a One-to-Many association. The other side will be automatically added.
INFO! No change in entity configurations, no entities were updated.
INFO! The JDL has been successfully parsed
INFO! Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
```

And then I ran  ./mvnw -P-webpack and also yarn start on the different terminal.

[image]

[image]

Both are works perfectly and app runs on the localhost:8080 thru ./mvnw and also localhost:9000 from npm start.

Here is my currentr schemas (From http://localhost:9000/admin/docs) :

[image]

And here is my problem,  Although the schemas already imported perfectly but the **Entities Menu** is still Empty.

[image]

[image]

I have tried following sollution but nothing is work:

- Incognito browser to start with empty cache.
- ./mvnw  and also ./mvnw -P-webpack
- npm start

Any body can help me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `-P-webpack`, you deactivate webpack profile which means the frontend is not built by maven and not bundled in the backend, this works only if you access the frontend through the webpack dev server on port 9000.

Otherwise if you access it through the backend port (8080) you'll see the result of latest successful build which in your case was at the project generation when there was no entities yet.

Comment: I have tried with onlt ./mvnw, the result is still the same, maybe import-jdl  CLI doesn't generate anything in the VueJS code?

Comment: I don't use Vue blueprint. Have you tried running jhipster always with blueprint option?`jhipster --blueprint vuejs import-jdl ../jhipster.jdl`

Comment: I will try and let you know the result

Comment: Hi still the same, I got error when execute your "command", here is my screen video https://www.loom.com/share/bf752c662d674ca99f23adb4e8ff6965

Comment: Well you're showing only runtime not generation time. So far, you haven't shown what happens during import-jdl so I have no idea whether the entity client files were generated or not.

Comment: FYI, actually I got "-P-webpack" directly from  https://www.jhipster.tech/development/, it said that "If you will use live reload with npm start or yarn start then you can speed up server start up by excluding webpack tasks by: ./mvnw -P-webpack"

Comment: sorry for the video, I think the recording was not completed and missed some important part, will create new one

Comment: If you disable webpack profile, you must use webpack dev server port not the one from the java backend 8080.  In fact both syntax are correct: `-webpack` or `!webpack`

Comment: I tried on the both ports 8080 and 9000 all result the same, no entities on the menu, i am not sure but now I am trying to install it:  yarn add jhipster-core

Comment: and it solved now, but not sure which one is the solver 1.  yarn add jhipster-core or 2. Runs Jhipster outside the container

Comment: I got the following error everytime I execute:  jhipster --blueprint vuejs ;
ERROR! Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at JHipsterClientGenerator.setupSharedOptions (/home/jhipster/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2119:33)
    at JHipsterClientGenerator.setupClientOptions (/home/jhipster/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2135:14)

Comment: I think the problem comes from the Dockerfile from https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/Dockerfile , because it work properly on my Host but wrong on my container (I build my own image using exactly from the github without modification)

Comment: @YusufIbrahim, if Docker was the main problem of your issue, could you unmark this answer as a *Solution*?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your header/menues module?
I lost all my entities list when I upgraded.

It was removed from `src/main/webapp/app/shared/layout/menus.entities.tsx` as it seems (using react). For those using Angular, check the same module.

Reverting changes made by the generator solved the problem for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generating JHipster project directly from JDL reproduces the issue. I hit it with Angular, so it is not Vue related.

I got solution by splitting this single step:

```
jhipster import-jdl my-jdl-file.jdl
```

to:

```
jhipster
jhipster import-jdl my-jdl-file.jdl
```

or to:

```
jhipster import-jdl my-jdl-file-application-part-only.jdl
jhipster import-jdl my-jdl-file-entities-part.jdl
```

It solves the "no entities" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regenerating the entire code of all microservices and gateway into a new folder using jhipster jdl command is an option. It worked for me.

```
jhipster jdl sample.jdl
```